# Visual studio 2012 intellisense for method definitions

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, intellisense

I've been using VS2005 and now I'm switching to VS2012.

In 2005, after I write method declaration:

```
class A
{
   void foo(int p1, double p2);
}
```

And then when I start to write method definition:

```
void A::
```

intellisense would offer me both just method name (foo) and its full signature (foo(int p1, double p2)), which I found quite convenient.

For some reason VS2012 (and VS2010 as well) doesn't do it - it only offers the name.

Is there some configuration which is off by default for some reason or the feature has been deprecated?

Does VS2012 suggest any other convenient way to write method definitions in files other than the header with class definition?

Comment: I've mostly been stuck in the C# world the past years, but intellisense in 10 and 12 for c++ is unfortunately useless. I miss vs6 ;) WTB R# for c++.